# didDeselectItemAtIndexPath doesn't get called.

Tags: swift

I'm currently building an app for fevorite video games. 
Part of the development is to make a VC that will show data from tableView. 
However, when in storyboards i connected table cell to a detailedVC with a segue - i got an error. 
When I deleted that segue and made connection one more time from the view controller itself to the detailedVC - my "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" is not called anymore.
Here is a link to project's github: https://github.com/flostik2008/Favorite-Games .
Appreciate anyone who would participate.

Comment: Post your code and show us what you've tried. If 3li's answer did help, make an appropriate action. But it nice to provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your code inside `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` method rather than `tableView(_:didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:)` method

Comment: it worked. 
was "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" deprecated? 
I actually remember how  "didSelecRowAtIndexPath" popped up, and I forcefully removed it, because in tutorials that i'm watching (Mark Price from Udemy) the "...ItemAtIndexPath" was used.

Comment: Found the answer - one is from Collection View Delegate, the other is from Table View Delegate.